# Creating a Installpackage for mac

Tags: bash, macos

I have a lot of Programms that i always need to install to a new mac. I wanted to simplify this process through an installpackage. I allready tried Iceberg with some success but have a specific error. What i want to do with iceberg is to unpack all the packages and start a script to install it and delete the packages after. I can make a package that unpacks the packages in my destination but the iceberg Programm wont execute the script i add in postinstall. the script itself works fine when i use it through terminal. the Script i am using is

```
##!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Virtualbox.pkg -target /
```

iceberg packs the script in the programm but never uses it.

Comment: What output or error do you see when using the `-verbose` flag with `installer`? Try `sudo installer -verbose -pkg /Library/Virtualbox.pkg -target /`

Comment: there is no error. if i use installer in terminal in does what it is made to do. my problem is that iceberg or packages or Packagemaker dont execute the script in postinstall.

Comment: PackageMaker is no longer supported by Apple; only `Installer.app` and `installer` are supported by Apple on OS X.

Comment: but Iceberg and packages are still supportet?

Comment: [Iceberg](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html) is a third party product and I am not sure what packages is. Apple's developer tools now only include `productbuild` and `pkgbuild`. I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the `postinstall` script. The first line should contain only one hash (#):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

If the `.pkg` works with `installer` and **Installer.app**, then it is a correct package. All other tools are made by third parties and may not support the latest `pkg` formats and features.

### Lacking Permission?

Using `sudo` in your package script may cause the script to pause forever or instantly fail. How will the `sudo` command interact with the user to get the super user's credentials?

Remove `sudo` and make your script [test for permission](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-root-user-check-script.html) to install before continuing, otherwise print an error and exit:

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "You must be a root to run this script" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi
```

It is the responsibility of `installer` to gain the appropriate authorisation rights and run the package's scripts using those rights. Within your package, specify that it needs administrator rights to ensure this happens.

### Logs and Errors

Use the `verbose` flag with [`installer`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/installer.8.html) to see each step of the installation process and to see errors:

```
sudo installer -verbose -pkg /Library/Virtualbox.pkg -target /
```

### Apple Package Tools

Installer packages on OS X are typically built with the tools [`pkgbuild`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) and `productbuild`. These two Apple tools support pre and post scripts; see the `--scripts` flag.

## AutoPkg

Mac system administrators often use the open source [`autopkg`](https://github.com/autopkg/autopkg) tool to create packages:

> AutoPkg is an automation framework for OS X software packaging and distribution, oriented towards the tasks one would normally perform manually to prepare third-party software for mass deployment to managed clients.

You may find AutoPkg is a better approach to simplifying the setting up of new Macs.

Comment: even with the changes to the code still dosent work. Iceberg wont execute it in postinstall

Comment: but as far as i learned about autopkg is that it is an deployment tool and not a pkg genarating tool. I need to bundle all the pkg and app files to a pkg an execute it from a stick for example. Am I right about autopkg or am i just too stupid to find the right code to do so

Comment: AutoPkg is very capable but may be too much for your needs. See https://github.com/autopkg/autopkg/wiki/Getting-Started to get started.

Comment: do i need to install autopkg or git on a new mac to use a recipe. If so than no matter how good i will write the recipe the whole thing is useless to me. What I need is a prepackaged bundle that works even without an Internetconnection.